# Bootstrap carousel is not working. Not activated

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using jquery and Bootstrap delivered with Visual studio. Bootstrap v3.3.7, jQuery JavaScript Library v2.2.0

It seems it is a problem of the script not activating the carousel, although I have everything in place.
The scripts come from the Layout page of an asp net core application. I transcribed here only the output in html.

Html Code:

```
<!--Carousel Wrapper-->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <!--Indicators-->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!--/.Indicators-->
            <!--Slides-->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <!--First slide-->
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <!--/First slide-->
                <!--Second slide-->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(129).jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <!--/Second slide-->
                <!--Third slide-->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
                <!--/Third slide-->
            </div>
            <!--/.Slides-->
            <!--Controls-->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
            <!--/.Controls-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
```

Scripts at the end of page:

```
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>



    <script src="/js/site.js"></script>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#myCarousel').carousel();

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any messages in the console? Always include console output when asking questions.

Comment: but there is a function called carousel in bootstrap 3.3.7, i have checked. is it not working?

Comment: @VTodorov of which console are you talking?

Comment: The browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel()
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505881502353-a1986add3762?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=79770836c467adb5a78c392855fb1557&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Seashore
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504416285472-eccf03dd31eb?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=a121a890a07652296c0cff8d74f242ef&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          Chinese Restorant
      </div>
    </div>
 
 <div class="item">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506153456649-ed4ed08d1e0c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=d631d4911c05368cf6699b828116473d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
          Cars
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: So you just copied the code from w3schools and pasted it here?

Comment: I copied the code for carousel from one website, but I verified that the tags exist in my version of bootstrap. Is it bad to copy the code? Copied or not copied this does not answer the question. It should work, but it is not.

Comment: yes so what did you get result or not in a easy way and i given link there from where i copied ...and bro that is officially tutorials website

Answer (score 0):

I changed the class of the items from: "carousel-item" to "item" and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!--Indicators-->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <!--/.Indicators-->
            <!--Slides-->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <!--First slide-->
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(130).jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <!--/First slide-->
                <!--Second slide-->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(129).jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <!--/Second slide-->
                <!--Third slide-->
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
                <!--/Third slide-->
            </div>
            <!--/.Slides-->
            <!--Controls-->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
            <!--/.Controls-->
        </div>
        <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You are working with the 3.3.7 version but the code is for 4.x version. Change to 4.x version code or remove the `class Carousel-item to item`